# How to Display A Message without return the value

Tags: java, exception, data-structures, queue

In this function if isEmpty , i don't wanna return 0 or any numeric value .. i just wanna display the message when i sout dequeue from main . How can i do that by handling exception w this custom message or by any other way ?

```
public int dequeue()
    {
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Queue is Empty !"); 
            return 0;
        }
        else{ 
            first++; 
            int x = arr[first]; 
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Small tip: You can say if(isEmpty()) since you are working in the same class as the  isEmpty() method. this.method() is almost never necessary

Comment: @faris Got it thanks :)
But it means that i don't need to use "this." at any situation in java ?

Comment: There are other situations where you might use the keyword "this" like setting global variables in the constructor or using the class object as a parameter in another method, but as for calling a method in the same class like you used it, I can't think of any times when you would need it.

Answer (score 2):

```
public int dequeue() throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    first++; 
    int x = arr[first]; 
    return x;
}
```

And when you call it:

```
try {
    dequeue();
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Queue is empty!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you ^^
But can i do anything to handle or deal w that before calling the fn in main ?

Comment: Not unless you return a 0 value, or something equivalent, which you said you didn't want to do.  The problem is that once you declare a return type, you MUST return that type.  That means that if you handle the exception inside that method, you will still have to return something, and what do you return if you weren't able to dequeue anything?  So those are the options- handle the exception inside the method and return a 0 or default value; or catch the exception from main.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void dequeue()
    {
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Queue is Empty !"); 
        }
        else{ 
            first++; 
            int x = arr[first]; 
        }
    }
```

This should print the line if the first statement evaluates true without requiring you to return anything

Comment: I thought about that but i wanna return the dequeued value if the 2nd case is true also i need to learn how to deal w exceptions in cases like that

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the program will work fine if you remove the return statement. But it is good to use a return statement to avoid unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Suppose it's necessary to add return statement , how i deal with this situation ?

Comment: Instead of return 0, throw a custom exception like QEmptyException and then handle this exception when you are calling dequeue() function.